# django ALLOWED_HOSTS redirects to a local ip

Tags: django, debugging, nginx, gunicorn

My project runs when I set debug=True.
When I set debug to False and ALLOWED_HOSTS to ['*'] it redirect me to the local IP my gunicorn is running on.

When I set ALLOWED_HOSTS to my domain I get Server Error (500)

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

My problem was in nginx configuration, I had to set the host. I added the following to the configuration file and it worked.

> ```
>           proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
>           proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>           proxy_set_header  Host mysite.com;
>           proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
>           proxy_redirect    off;
>           proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
debug =False that mean your
apps are running in production mode which going to require a localhost 
so you will be redirect to that local ip address. now if you 
set the ALLOWED_HOSTS to the domain by default you should 
change your hostname to that domain name. 

so execute this command line first 
$ sudo gksu gedit  /etc/hostname  to edit the hostname file and
add the line www.yourdomain.com

$ sudo  /etc/hosts and add the line:
127.0.0.1   www.yourdomain.com localhost

After that  set ALLOWED_HOSTS to your domain name and see what you get.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get Server Error (500) after the changes.

Comment: My problem was in nginx configuration. I updated my post. Thanks!